# How do I change the style of the body, from a component that is elsewhere?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

How do I change the style of the body, from a component that is elsewhere?

My component :

```
export const ModalComponent = () => {
  const visible = true;
  return {
   <Modal>
    <Title>
   </Modal>
  }
}
```

Global styles (if visible === true / body { background: green })

```
const Global {
 body {
  background: red;
 }
}
```

Comment: Since you're using a functional component there, I'd suggest `useEffect` and just use `document.body` to manually manipulate the styles.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ternary operator in inline styling

```js
style={ (visible=true) ? {backgroundColor:'green'} : {backgroundColor:'red'}
```